# How to controlling a mouse with a joystick and button using python, gpiozero

Tags: python-3, ubuntu, mouse

I am trying to use the GPIO pins from my raspy berry pi to control my mouse
I have a joystick connected to these gpio pins
pin 24 - mouse up
pin 25 - mouse down
pin 5 - mouse left
pin 6 - mouse right

and I have button connected to these pins
pin 6 - ground
pin 11 - Right mouse click
pin 27 - page up (50% of the viewport)
pin 22 - page down (50% of the viewport)
pin 23 - esc

my problem is whe I use python librarys such as pyautogui there is some screen erros that come up that deal with xlib so I am looking for another way.
I dont know how to assign the `wait_for_press` to the right mouse click or the mouse move.
if someone can show me how to assign a button that would be much appreciated!

This was my original hello world test for one of the gpio buttons but i only used it to check if I have everything wired correctly.

```
#right mouse click button
buttonStart =  Button(17)
buttonStart.wait_for_press()
"print("Start!")"
```

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from gpiozero import Button
# whenever I import this it causes errors
#import pyautogui

#button to move the page up(viewport 50%)
buttonPageUp = button(27)
buttonPageUp.wait_for_press()

#button to move page down(viewport 50%)
buttonPageDown = button(22)
buttonPageDown.wait_for_press()

#right mouse click button
buttonStart =  Button(17)
buttonStart.wait_for_press()
# this was to test the button "print("Start!")"

#esc keybourd key button
buttonEsc = Button(23)
buttonEsc.wait_for_press()

#joystick, controls mouse on screen

stickUp = Button(24)
stickUp.wait_for_press()
stickDown = Button(25)
stickDown.wait_for_press()
stickleft = Button(5)
stickLeft.wait_for_press()
stickRight = Button(6)
stickRight.wait_for_press()
```

Comment: `wait_for_press` is blocking, so nothing can happen until a button is pressed, so you want to declare all your buttons together at the top. Also read up on the different ways of detecting button presses: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-difference-between-when-pressed-is-pressed-and-wait-for-press

Comment: I recommend you open a new question about pyautogui with details of what the error is - as that's an unrelated problem to detecting button presses with gpiozero